# Create multidimensional array with simple html dom parser?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using simple html dom parser. I want to put an array in my `$ret['ingredients']` array.

This is the HTML code I want to parse

```
<div class="ingredients">
<p>1 dl vatten</p>
<p>30 g smör</p>
<p>¾ dl vetemjöl</p>
<p>1 stort ägg</p>
</div>
```

and want the result look like this

```
Array 
( 
    [ingredients] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => '1 dl vatten' 
            [1] => '30 g smör'
            [2] => '¾ dl vetemjöl'
            [3] => '1 stort ägg' 
        ) 
)
```

But when I try this code

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="ingredients"] p') as $element) {
    $ret['ingredients'] = array($element->innertext);
        }
```

I get this result

```
Array 
( 
    [ingredients] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => '1 dl vatten 30 g smör ¾ dl vetemjöl 1 stort ägg' 
        ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be rather:

```
$ret['ingredients'] = array();
foreach($html->find('div[class="ingredients"] p') as $element) {
   $ret['ingredients'][] = $element->innertext;
}
```